# Could someone please help me with sklearn.metrics.roc_curve's use and what does the function expect?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to construct 2 numpy ndarray-s from a networkx Graph's data structures that look like a list of tuples and a simple list. I would like to make a roc curve where

1. the validation set is the above mentioned list of tuples of the edges of a G graph that I was trying to construct like this:

```
x = []

for i in G_orig.nodes():
    for j in G_orig.nodes():
        if j > I and (i, j) not in G.edges():
            if (i, j) in G_orig.edges():
                x.append((i, j, 1))
            else:
                x.append((i, j, 0))

y_validation = np.array(x)
```

It looks something like this: [(1, 344, 1), (2, 23, 0), (3, 5, 0), ...... (333, 334, 1)].

The first 2 numbers mean 2 nodes, the 3rd one means whether there is an edge between them. 1 means edge, 0 means no edge.

2. Then roc_curve expects something called y_score in the documentation. I have a list for that made with a method called preferential attachment, therefore I named it pref_att_types. I tried to make a numpy array of it in case the roc_curve expects only it.

```
positive_class_predicted_probabilities = np.array(pref_att_types)
```

3.Then I just did what we used in class.

```
FPRs, TPRs, thresholds = roc_curve(y_validation,
                                   positive_class_predicted_probabilities,
                                   pos_label=1)
```

It is literally just Ctrl C + Ctrl V. But it says Value error and 'multiclass-multioutput format is not supported'. Please note that I am not a programmer just someone who studies to be a mathematics analyst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument, `y_true`, needs to be just the true labels, in this case 0/1 without the pair of nodes.  Just be sure that the indices of the arrays `y_validation` and `pref_att_types` match

Answer (score -1):

The code below draws the ROC curves for two RF models:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
#create array of probabilities
y_test_predict1_probaRF = rf1.predict_proba(X_test)
y_test_predict2_probaRF = rf2.predict_proba(X_test)
RFfpr1, RFtpr1, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_test_predict1_probaRF[:,1])
RFfpr2, RFtpr2, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_test_predict2_probaRF[:,1])

def plot_roc_curve (fpr, tpr, label = None):
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, linewidth = 2, label = label)
    plt.plot([0,1], [0,1], "k--")
    plt.axis([0,1,0,1])
    plt.xlabel("False positive rate")
    plt.ylabel("True positive rate")
    
plot_roc_curve (RFfpr1,RFtpr1,"RF1")
plot_roc_curve (RFfpr2,RFtpr2,"RF2")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```